# Spring Security Basic Auth Password Rotation Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

Experts,,

I have a spring boot 2.5.5 application(embedded tomcat) where I have to configure the basic auth.

This is the class I have that does the work for me

```
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

The issue is I just need to enter the user/password once in the browser and it works for any subsequent request. Furthermore, I don't need to supply the new username/password after the server restarts which is driving me crazy - the app still works and I can access my APIs/pages.

Even if i assume the browser is somehow saving the username and password it should not work once the server is restarted as the password gets changed - isnt it ?

Update II:

Following the advice from *M. Deinum* I made the session stateless and it worked. I then went on to implement Basic Auth with InMemoryUserDetailsManager and added the below code and we are back to the same issue again. The credentials seem to be again stored in session and I need not pass them for the subsequent request.

```
@Autowired
    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User
                .builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMINISTRATOR")

                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
```

Comment: Once the server is restrated.. ? Are you able to access the page without login ??
Ellaborate your issue.

Comment: Dont update your question to ask something else mid way through. You asked something and it was answered. You then accept the answer and move on. Stack overflow is not a forum its a Q&A site. You changing the question mid way through tells us that you are not fully understanding what answer you are seeking.

Comment: Again, as I stated in the answer, that is how basic authentication works. Once authenticated the browser will send the username/password for each request. That is build in browser functionality... So unless you rewrite the browser (or find some secret flag in your browser) this is how Basic Auth is designed to work.

Comment: @M.Deinum i added 'http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)' to the configure method so i expect that the calls should be stateless

Comment: Have you actually **read** the answer... 1. Http Basic after successful authentication always send the username/password (which is what still happens and making it stateless doesn't prevent that, you have to rebuild your browser) 2. Stateles helps for not storing the authentication in the session which prevents the still being authenticated after a restart. Those are 2 different and unrelated things. I strongly suggest you read on how basic authentication works.

Comment: @Tokyo you clearly have not done your research since you dont know what stateless actually means, and how basic authentication works and how browsers work. You cant ask a question if you do not understand the answer. We cant teach you the basics, stack overflow is not a school. If you dont understand the answer given you need to start googling. To us it feels like you dont understand what question you are asking, you dont understand the problem. So as pointed out, read up on what BASIC authentication is. Learn what session based authentication is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would expect it to work with your current configuration.

When successfully authenticated with basic authentication the browser will send the username/password for all other subsequent requests. So this is as expected.

Another thing is that, by default, Spring Security will use the HTTP Session to store the user information. A session-cookie is also sent with each request so that the session state can be restored for each request.

This session state is, by default for your servlet container, saved to disc when you stop the server, when you restart and the session is still valid (not timed out) it will still have the authentication.

You can fix this by making Spring Security not use a session (set the session mode to stateless).

```java
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

The drawback of this is that it will re-authenticate each request (which takes some time and thus impacts your performance slightly). But it should give an error after restart now, as you changed the password.